# How to use multiple profiles in Opera 37?

Tags: opera

I would like to use multiple network profiles, with their own cookies, history, etc. The goal is to use easily different network logins for different sites simultaneously. How is it possible?

P.s. Doing that on the Stackexchange is officially [allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104903/multiple-accounts-in-stack-overflow).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the **[`--user-data-dir`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md)** flag :

> The user data directory contains data specific to a given user. Some
> examples of this type of data are: history, bookmarks, and cookies.
>
> You can  start Chromium with a custom user data directory in order
> to run multiple instances at the same time.